# Display values into blocks

Tags: html, css

I have these value which I would like to display into key-value pairs similar to table:

```
<div class="element-box">
  <div class="details-wrapper">
    <p><b class="label">Remote IP</b>{{apiattempt.remote_ip}}</p>
    <p><b class="label">Raw Request</b>
      <pre>
        {{apiattempt.raw_request | xmlBeautyfier }}
      </pre>
    <p><b class="label">Raw Response</b>{{apiattempt.raw_response | xmlBeautyfier }}</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS code:

```
details-wrapper {
  padding: 20px 0;

  h4 {
    margin-bottom: 0;
  }

  .activity {
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    font-size: .8em;
    color: #9e9e9e;
  }

  p {
    .label {
      display: inline-block;
      width: 100px;
      margin-right: 10px;
    }
  }
}
```

I want to use  instead of

I tried this:

API Attempt details

```
<div class="element-box">
  <div class="details-wrapper">
    <div><b class="label">Remote IP</b>{{apiattempt.remote_ip}}</div>
    <div><b class="label">Raw Request</b><pre>{{apiattempt.raw_request | xmlBeautyfier }}</pre></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I get this visual result:

[image]

Can you give some advice how to fix this padding?

I want to get his visual result:

[image]

Comment: You could use flexbox or css grid to build this, as well as a table

Answer (score 0):

While actual tables are really usefull here, and grid and flexbox are interesting options you actually had most of the layout fixed. It simply breaks because `<pre>` is a block element by default. Setting its `display` to `inline` or `inline-block` should fix your problem.

Note that block elements always try to take up the complete horizontal space.

CSS:

```
pre {
    display: inline;
}
```

Comment: Added example, sorry I thought I was clear on it being CSS.